# Is it safe to edit the version list?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-versions

When you have the right format for versions, but reference a version that doesn't exist (as far as Documentation is concerned), you see something like this:

> [image: [gte Perl 1]-->]

Will I mess other sections up by editing the versions (like the name)? And how will the topic-specific versioning appear?

Comment: How that was approved?

Comment: @Braiam The picture is from an earlier draft. (You don't need approval to write a draft.) It was fixed when it was reviewed and added to Docs.

Comment: Feels like the display logic for invalid versions should be altered so that it at least displays some kind of warning à la broken citations on Wikipedia, rather than displaying the broken HTML comment.

Comment: @Josh I agree, but I'm not how it would work. While breaking the page I'm editing would be bad, breaking *every other page in the tag* is a whole lot worse. What would I do, edit EVERYTHING? I can only have 10 drafts at once...

Comment: [Red freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/282658), why yes I'll upvote this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I feared, I eventually changed the version list in a way that broke the formatting. (You *lied* to me, Help Center: I broke it and peer review didn't help.) Nobody can really be blamed since the change only affected other locations (really just one Example I made).

Note to everyone: the name of the technology is the line that is directly above the table:

```
## What I wanted the name to be
### Some notes that unfortunately became the name

|versions|release date|
```

In other words, **simply changing the name is enough to mess things up.** Yes, we should probably have a FR to change this behavior.

While I await approval (and/or try to get it approved by including [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex?tab=proposedchanges) here), I will share what happens when you mess up the versions.

**It's not as bad as I feared, but it should be fixed ASAP.**

You mess up the version picker:

[image: Version Picker]

(I don't know what happens to the picked versioning for existing topics.)

Any comments (in examples) using the version show nothing:

> [image: Comment not rendering]

Also, it makes review history look weird. Compare the first and second revisions (both mine) listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/revisions/4524).